# ¿Oración condicional o completiva?

Tags: sintaxis

¿Me podríais aclarar mi duda por favor? ¿Cómo se debe interpretar esta oración: como una oración condicional (condicional + subjuntivo; con la conjunción *que* en vez de *si*) o como una oración completiva?

> Habría sido una lástima que su talento se perdiera.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4):

> —Habría sido una lástima que su talento se perdiera. (= no se perdió).

Estas construcciones se dejan sin la otra cláusula condicional, pues queda claro, bajo el contexto, lo que se quiere decir:

> —Habría sido [...] se perdiera **si no la hubiesen contratado**. (= su talento no se perdió porque, al final, la contrataron).

Por lo anterior, esta es una oración condicional.

Comment: No es que yo esté interesado en saber si la oración es condicional o completiva (pues no se eso para que sirve :-) ) pero no veo que esto responda lo que se pregunta. Creo que a esta respuesta le falta un pedacito. Lo que entiendo es que no es condicional porque la clausula condicional se omite ¿es así?

Comment: @DGaleano Se pide por la interpretación; esa es la que siempre doy a estas estructuras. ¿A qué otra cosa crees que apunta?

Comment: No es que OP no entienda el significado. La pregunta es **"¿Se interpreta como condicional o se interpreta completiva?"** Pienso que la respuesta debe decir "es una frase condicional" o "es completiva".

Comment: @DGaleano Ah, quizás no se aprecia en mi respuesta, pero quiero mostrar que es condicional.

Comment: Creo que se están confundiendo aquí dos planos de descripción. Sintácticamente esto es una completiva sin duda. Semánticamente se puede interpretar como equivalente a una condicional (pero no basta con cambiar *que* por *si*).

Comment: @pablodf76 Nunca cambié *que* por *si*; de hecho, continué con la cláusula anterior para añadir la condicional.

Comment: @Ustanak Sí, no quise decir eso, sino que OP implicaba eso.

Comment: @pablodf76 Acabo de leer de nuevo me di cuenta del matiz que se quiere hacer. No tengo tiempo para editar mi respuesta, pero o lo haré apenas pueda.

Answer (score 0):

La frase en la pregunta es:

- Habría sido una lástima que su talento se perdiera.

Este tipo de oración se llama: una oración con una proposición conjunción completiva o subordinada

> Dado a sus características y funciones, las conjunciones completivas pueden introducir una proposición subordinada sustantiva, una enunciativa o una de carácter interrogativa.
>
> De esta manera, este tipo de conjunciones pueden hacer referencia al sujeto, al objeto directo de una oración o realiza run a interrogación indirecta. En los primeros dos casos se trata de la conjunción completiva **que**, mientras que en el último de ellos de la conjunción **si**.

[Exemplos en el mismo texto:]

- No me gusta que hagan malos comentarios de mis amigos.
- Les pido de favor que me disculpen.
  [...]

  Tú quieres que sea amable

El enlace es: [conyunciones completivas](https://www.scribd.com/document/341492521/Conjunciones-completivas)

**El tiempo de los verbos sigue la regla siguiente**:

- Habría sido una lástima que su talento se perdiera.

**Habría sido** es un tiempo **condicional compuesto perfecto**.

> 5. CONDICIONAL PERFECTO COMPUESTO
>      Se construye con el verbo HABER en condicional y un participio.
>      Verbo HABER en condicional: habría, habrías, habría, habríamos, habríais, habrían.
>      **Se utiliza con el pluscuamperfecto del modo subjuntivo** (explicación más abajo) en oraciones compuestas, para expresar situaciones hipotéticas que no sucedieron. Si hubieras estudiado más, no te habrías rajado en el examen. Nos habrías podido ayudar si hubieras querido.

[enlace sobre los tiempos de los verbos](https://colombia-sa.com/espanol/significado_compuestos.html)

A mi parecer, no hay una gran diferencia de sentido entre:

- Habría sido una lástima que su talento se perdiera. [no se perdió]
- Habría sido una lástima si su talento se perdiera. [no se perdió]

Si el verbo de la primera proposición está en el condicional perfecto compuesto, el verbo en la proposición subordinada tiene que estár en el pluscuamperfecto del subjuntivo.

En términos prácticos (y no necesariamente formales) la frase utiliza los mismos tiempos de verbo que se utiliza en oraciones con si, que son las condicionales.

Encontré este trabajo sobre la cuestión:

[condicionales sin si](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/3697049.pdf)

Este tipo de oración no está clasificada como "canónica". Pero me parece que se puede clasificar como una oración con todos los rasgos de condicionalidad.

Comment: personalmente creo que el usar el "que" esta mal en una oración condicional o completiva ya que el "que" no esta sujeto al un resultado si no que indica el resultado: el "Qué". mientras que el "si" es el condicionante que nos explica el "por que".

para entenderlo mas fácilmente, estas oraciones en ingles no pueden intercambiar el "if" por que "that"

Comment: Para mi la forma correcta seria solo : "habría sido una lastima SI su talento se perdiera" y "fue una lastima QUE su talento se perdiera"

Comment: Puede estar mal, pero se dice y se oje. Quise evitar toda referencia al inglés. El inglés y el español son muy diferentes. Yo dije claramente que la frase no es canónica. Y estaba intentando responder a la pregunta.

Comment: El irrealis de: "Fue una lástima que su talento se perdió" sería:  "Habría sido una lástima que su talento se perdiera." Personalmente, no veo razón aqui para utilisar perdiera con fue. fue/perdió.

Comment: También la he escuchado como parte del lenguaje, pero cuando trato de entenderla es cuando pienso internamente "ESTA MAL", sobre todo al momento de escribir y siento que es por eso que nace la duda de esta pregunta, si se esta completando o si se esta condicionando y el intercambiar "que" con "si" lo vuelve mas difícil.